# Put Request in chrome is not binding DTO

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, asp.net-web-api2, put, dto

I am facing strange problem although spent much time but still unable to resolve it

Previously put request was working fine i had an issue with

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0

I resolved it by adding

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

although it resolve the issue but my put method wasn't working after scratching my head i came to know its not binding model to my DTO although ModelState.IsValid == true but my DTO model is null and this happens only with put request all other request are working fine such as get, getall, delete, post and this is happening only in chrome. In Firefox put request is working fine.

I am unable to understand if ModelState is true then why chrome is not binding data to my DTO following are header request of chrome and Firefox respectively

Chrome

```
PUT /api/AddressTypeAPI/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:xxxx
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 194
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:xxxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Bearer xxxx
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:xxxx/AddressType/Index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Firefox

```
Host: localhost:xxxx
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 179
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
Authorization: Bearer xxxx
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Referer: http://localhost:xxxx/AddressType/Index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
```

I wonder why content length is different

Following are details as required

My angular JS function which calls webapi

```
 service.put = function (ID, DataBundle) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "put",
        url: url + "/" + ID,
        data: { DataBundle: DataBundle }
    }).catch(exceptionHandler);
    return request;
}

DataBundle-->
Active:"Y"
Code:"0002"
CreateDate:null
CreateUser:null
Description:"Office Address"
ID:2
ModifyDate:"2015-10-19T02:15:06.6241496"
ModifyUser:1
Name:"Office"
__proto__:Object
```

Sever side code for put request from chrome
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNO3h.png)

DTO class to bind incoming model

```
public class ParamDTO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Active { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CreateUser { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ModifyUser { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifyDate { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UserLevelID { get; set; }
        public string StatusType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the bodies of the requests of both Firefox and Chrome to your question? Next to that, the signature of the action method and the classes used in that signature would be helpful as well.

Comment: are you talking about the calling method of JS? do you think these headers are having much difference I mean what is causing put request through chrome that its not binding data to my DTO. wait lemme take all screenshots that would be easy for u to understand

Comment: I'm talking about the bodies of the HTTP requests. Currently you've only added the headers. Adding the bodies of the request might shed some light on the question why the content lengths differ. Next to that, adding the signature of the ApiControllers method that receives the PUT helps investigating why the ModelState is valid but the DTO is empty.

Comment: sorry for mess up i was trying to describe it in pictorial form but i was unable to post more pics. Databundle of both request is same (i.e from chrome and firefox model bind with same values as databundle if request is from firefox) please let me know if u need more info

Comment: I still would like to see the bodies of the requests. Do you have [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) installed? Start it up, execute exactly the same request from Firefox and Chrome (e.g. PUT the same DataBundle to http://localhost:yourport/api/AddressTypeAPI/1). Retrieve the bodies of these request from Fiddler and add them to your question.

Comment: I am unable to understand this even the Firefox is binding null to DTO :( I haven't use fiddler before just installed it there are different tabs on right pane are u talking about header tab's content? sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done
my angularJS calling function was having problem
this line

```
data: { DataBundle: DataBundle }
```

should be

```
 data: DataBundle
```

I am not sure why it was sometimes working with firefox. If anyone can contribute to explain this that would be appreciating